# Issue with Django data migration when model changes later

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

Let's say I have a Django model that looks like this:

```
class MyEntity(models.Model):
    my_first_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I create a data migration that inserts some values in MyEntity model.

Then I create a schema migration that adds another attribute "my_second_attribute".

If I run ./migrate.py on a fresh database, running the data migration fails and Django complains that myentity.my_second_attribute doesn't exist!

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: did you run `./manage.py makemigrations` and then `./manage.py migrate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure that your [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) function does this:

```
Person = apps.get_model("yourappname", "Person")
```

Rather than using this:

```
from yourappname.models import Person
```

The former will assume database schema and models as defined by previous schema migration(s) (as specified in `Migration.dependencies`).

The latter will use current sources which may go way ahead of the state known to migration files.